# goaccess won't run when called from CGI script

Tags: bash, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to make a CGI script (for nginx) that outputs an html page containing the usage statistics for my server. I'm using goaccess 0.7.1 and CentOS 5 x86.

I've configured nginx to run my bash script (`stats.sh`) for requests on port 8080.

The bash script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log | goaccess -a > stats.html

echo Content-Type: text/html
echo Content-Length: $(stat -c%s stats.html)
echo
cat stats.html
```

When I run `./stats.sh`, everything works fine. It prints a bunch of html code in the console window, and if I open stats.html, I see a bunch of html code.

**THE PROBLEM IS**, when I try to access `http://www.mydomain.com:8080/`, I just get a blank page. Now when I open stats.html on the server, it's completely empty.

I've confirmed the following permissions:

- `stats.sh`: `-rwxr-xr-x`
- `stats.html`: `-rw-rw-rw-`
- `goaccess`: `-rwxr-xr-x`

I also know that CGI is working properly because if I modify `stats.sh` to only output the contents of `stats.html` (without writing to the file), it works fine when I hit `http://www.mydomain.com:8080/`; it just sends whatever data was in `stats.html` from before. So something is going wrong with calling goaccess in a CGI script. Does anyone know why?

**UPDATE**

I also tried this:

```
echo "<!DOCTYPE hmtl><html><body>TEST</body></html>" > stats.html
```

and it works fine when I hit `http://www.mydomain.com:8080/`, so something is going wrong when running `goaccess` from FastCGI.

I also tried specifying the full path to `goaccess` (`/usr/local/bin/goaccess`):

```
/var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log | /usr/local/bin/goaccess -a >stats.html 2>stats.err
```

but this also did not work.

Comment: Sounds like permissions issue, did you check your `/var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log`?

Comment: It doesn't show anything from my :8080 request. The last entry is:
`014/08/07 20:05:51 [error] 24993#0: *610 access forbidden by rule, client: x.x.x.x, server: _, request: "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x:8080"`.
I don't have a page called `/manager/html`, nor did I ever request it, so I assume this is from a crawler. All of the errors from the last 2 days are similar to this one.

Comment: I tried your script on Apache (CGI), first it wasn't writing anything to stats.html (blank page), I did `chmod a+rwx /usr/lib/cgi-bin` and it worked fine. I'll see if I can fire up an nginx instance and test it.

Comment: Perhaps writing the goaccess stderr log to a file can help clear things up: `goaccess -a >stats.html 2>stats.err`

Comment: I tried adding the `2>stats.err` part, but it doesn't generate the `stats.err` file at all when I run it from FastCGI. If I run the bash script manually, it generates `stats.err` as an empty file.

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to `chmod 666 stats.err`. It's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mydomainI finally got it to work! The main problem was my `.goaccessrc` file. I had foolishly created this file in `/root`, so obviously non-root users could not read it. I moved it to `/etc` and it works fine now. Here is the final code for my bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log | /usr/local/bin/goaccess -a -p /etc/.goaccessrc >stats.html 2>stats.err

echo Content-Type: text/html
echo Content-Length: $(stat -c%s stats.html)
echo
cat stats.html
```

Make sure to run `chmod 666 stats.err`.